# How to use matchadd to add exact word?

Tags: vimrc

Referring to answer from [this link.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5614/20720).

Adding two groups,

```
:highlight MyGroup1 ctermbg=green guibg=green
:highlight MyGroup2 ctermbg=blue guibg=blue
```

Then adding two words `foo` and `bar` into specific groups.

```
:call matchadd("MyGroup1", "foo")
:call matchadd("MyGroup2", "bar")
```

But how to make sure that the exact words `foo` is highlighted and not some conjunction word `bigwordwithfoo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `\<` and `\>` anchors around your pattern, to match word boundaries before and after your words.

```
:call matchadd("MyGroup1", '\<foo\>')
:call matchadd("MyGroup2", '\<bar\>')
```

You need single quotes, to prevent Vim from using `\` as an escape character.

See also:

- [`:help /\<`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3C)
- `:help matchadd()` for details on how pattern is used and matched.
- `:help literal-string` for how single quoted strings don't interpret backslashes as escape characters.

Comment: How to add pattern such that, highlight word `foo` only on those lines which contain other word `kookoo`

Comment: @RohanGhige You should ask that as a new question, that way you will get visibility on your question and possibly attract better answers. Please don't use comments for whole follow up questions, more like clarifications on the answer, if you didn't get it to work, etc...